# HTML Addin buttons

Tags: html

I have added 4 buttons to a page but I can no longer add more as they won't appear for me on screen. I beginning to code and this is my first project. some help, please?

[image]

I have added 4 buttons to a page but I can no longer add more as they won't appear for me on screen. I beginning to code and this is my first project. some help, please?

Comment: please, don't post links to images of text - they're susceptible to link-rot and frankly, it's a huge waste of bandwidth. Just copy the code and paste it into your question. Don't forget to apply the code-tags, otherwise your code wont be formatted or syntax highlighted and will look awful.

Comment: Please be concerned about your input elements height. That may be the problem!

Comment: alright will do sorry about that, and the first 4 buttons I added worked well, but the other 2 I added won't appear on screen, and there size are not too big that they wouldn't fit.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use that to make a button, use this to make a button(***CHANGE ALL OF THEM***):

```html
<!--your code-->
<button onclick="window.location.href='URL'">Text inside the button</button>
<!--your code-->
```

What you have to do is change 2 things:

1. The text between "<button ...>" and ""
2. The **URL** between "window.location.href=' " and the closing mark of "onclick"